# Mysql query takes more than 5 minutes

Tags: c#, mysql, database, database-performance

I have a MySQL database that has multiple tables. The SQL query in question will take more than 5 minutes to execute. One table that is queried is 'DeviceInfo' and has more than 21 Millions records.

The (C#) application executing this query receives a timeout during the execution of the query.

I have increased the  innodb_buffer_pool_size = 64M to 1G in My.ini for MySQl.

How can I reduce the execution time.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(pd.PatientId)   FROM DeviceInfo di   
  JOIN DeviceSession ds ON ds.DeviceSessionID = di.ByDevSessionId   
  JOIN UserSession us ON us.UserSessionId = ds.ByUserSessionId   
  JOIN PatientDetails pd ON pd.PatientDetailsId = us.ByPatientId   
  WHERE   di.SyncStatus = 0   ORDER BY us.UserStartSessionTime  Desc
```

The DeviceInfo table has 21,850,806 records

Comment: have you set an index ? Try to set it on all the id's you join. I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: run `explain select ....` and share the result into the question.

Comment: Can you provide the table definitions for each of these tables? You can do this by executing `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table;`

Answer (score 1):

Since you want just check the distinct `PatientId` from `PatientDetails` table try converting all the `Joins` to `exists` which will have better performance than Join

Also You can remove the `order by` at the end if you just want to see the distinct `PatientId` with out any order

```
SELECT pd.PatientId
FROM   PatientDetails pd
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   UserSession us
               WHERE  pd.PatientDetailsId = us.ByPatientId
                      AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                  FROM   DeviceSession ds
                                  WHERE  us.UserSessionId = ds.ByUserSessionId
                                         AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                                     FROM   DeviceInfo di
                                                     WHERE  ds.DeviceSessionID = di.ByDevSessionId
                                                            AND di.SyncStatus = 0)))
GROUP  BY pd.PatientId
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have indexes on those columns that you're joining and on the one in your where clause? Use the word `EXPLAIN SELECT...' before your query and look at what is output in the mysql cli, that will let you know if it is doing a full table scan or...